# Check the array of element in another array of set of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Let openstatus = ["Open","Created","Checked"]

Let obj = [
  { id: 00023434, Authore: tester, status: Approval }, 
  { id: 0002578, Authore: apitester, status: Open }, 
  { id: 0002847, Authore: usertester, status: Created },
{ id: 0002847, Authore: usertester, status: Draft },
]
```

Example :
Let status = "Draft"
obj.filter((e1)

return e1.status.includes(status)
);

from above one output will be below output:[id: 0002847, Authore: usertester, status: Draft]

When the status has all list of values ["Open","Created","Checked"] then how to filter it

I need to check the above openstatus of list of array status values match to check from obj array and to find to give last 2 records. can I know simple step to resolve this issue.As I am new to javascript

Comment: Unrelated, but be wary of numbers with leading zeros. It'd also be easier to deal w/ if the example was actual code. Are you asking how to get the last two elements of an array?

Comment: also possible unquoted strings

Comment: Yeah @DaveNewton I was looking for last 2 elements to return from filter search based on list of openstatus from obj filter status values

Comment: What output are you expecting given the code snippet? Please update the question with specifics--do you want the issues with a `status` of anything contained in `openstatus`, e.g., `Open` and `Created`? So it has nothing to do w/ returning the last two elements of an array, rather how to filter on a set of criteria?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have given the example. My only concern is when its single values to find based on filter and includes its gettting the result but multiple values in a list of array to find in another one status of anything contained in openstatus, e.g., Open and Created I was facing difficulty

Comment: What output are you expecting? A single integer: `2`? An object: `{ Open: 1, Created: 1, Checked: 0 }`? You need to fill in the gaps in your question as David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter using the condition that the `openstatus` array *includes* the element's status.

```js
let openstatus = ['Open', 'Created', 'Checked'];

let obj = [
  { id: 00023434, Authore: 'tester', status: 'Approval' }, 
  { id: 0002578, Authore: 'apitester', status: 'Open' }, 
  { id: 0002847, Authore: 'usertester', status: 'Created' },
  { id: 0002847, Authore: 'usertester', status: 'Draft' },
];

console.log(obj.filter(el => openstatus.includes(el.status)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. Give the documentation a read.

Comment: I know we can use filter but when list of openstatus that need to match in obj array fo list

Comment: @vijay What is preventing you from checking each item's `status` against the list of desired statuses?

Comment: @DaveNewton when I have list of values openstatus to check in obj array using filter and includes it will get the rresult. Because as i need to search all those openstatus values in obj then iam not gettign any result using filter with includes as mentioned